# Issue with importing Chainlink & Openzeppelin

Tags: python, openzeppelin, chainlink, brownie

[image: Advanced Collectible Contract]

[image: Brownie Config]

[image: brownie run scripts/advanced_collectible/deploy_advanced.py]

Currently trying to run a script and keep running into an error when trying to import chainlink and openzeppelin contracts. Not sure why, I looked at brownie pm list to make sure I have the correct versions install as well.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Code from AdvancedCollectible.sol:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract AdvancedCollectible is ERC721, VRFConsumerBase{
    uint256 public tokenCounter;
    enum Breed{PUG, SHIBA_INU, ST_BERNARD}
    //add other things
    mapping(bytes32 => address) public requestIdToSender;
    mapping(bytes32 => string) public requestIdToTokenURI;
    mapping(uint256 => Breed) public tokenIdToBreed;
    mapping(bytes32 => uint256) public requestIdToTokenId;
    event requestedCollectible(bytes32 indexed requestId); 

    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 public fee;

    constructor(address _VRFCoordinator, address _LinkToken, bytes32 _keyhash)
    public
    VRFConsumerBase(_VRFCoordinator, _LinkToken)
    ERC721("Dogges", "DOGGE")
    {
        keyHash = _keyhash;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; //0.1 LINK
    }
    function createCollectable(uint256 userProvidedSeed, string memory tokenURI) public returns (bytes32){
        bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyHash, fee, userProvidedSeed);
        requestIdToSender[requestId] = msg.sender;
        requestIdToTokenURI[requestId] = tokenURI;
        emit requestedCollectible(requestId);
    }
    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomNumber) internal override{
        address dogOwner = requestIdToSender[requestId];
        string memory tokenURI = requestIdToTokenURI[requestId];
        uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;
        _safeMint(dogOwner, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        Breed dogBreed = Breed(randomNumber % 3); 
        tokenIdToBreed[newItemId] = dogBreed;
        requestIdToTokenId[requestId] = newItemId;
        tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
    }
    function setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) public {
        require(
            _isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId),
            "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved"
        );
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, _tokenURI);
    }
}
```

Code from brownie.config.yaml

```
# exclude SafeMath when calculating test coverage
# https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.3/config.html#exclude_paths
reports:
  exclude_contracts:
    - SafeMath
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2'
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
```

Error:

```
Brownie v1.14.3 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.6.6
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

contracts/AdvancedCollectible.sol:3:1: ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
^--------------------------------------------------------^

contracts/AdvancedCollectible.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import ""@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
^-----------------------------------------------------------^
```

**Update**

Solution: corrected imports in AdvancedCollectible.sol to the following:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract AdvancedCollectible is ERC721, VRFConsumerBase{
    uint256 public tokenCounter;
    enum Breed{PUG, SHIBA_INU, ST_BERNARD}
    //add other things
    mapping(bytes32 => address) public requestIdToSender;
    mapping(bytes32 => string) public requestIdToTokenURI;
    mapping(uint256 => Breed) public tokenIdToBreed;
    mapping(bytes32 => uint256) public requestIdToTokenId;
    event requestedCollectible(bytes32 indexed requestId); 

    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 public fee;

    constructor(address _VRFCoordinator, address _LinkToken, bytes32 _keyhash)
    public
    VRFConsumerBase(_VRFCoordinator, _LinkToken)
    ERC721("Dogges", "DOGGE")
    {
        keyHash = _keyhash;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; //0.1 LINK
    }
    function createCollectable(uint256 userProvidedSeed, string memory tokenURI) public returns (bytes32){
        bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyHash, fee, userProvidedSeed);
        requestIdToSender[requestId] = msg.sender;
        requestIdToTokenURI[requestId] = tokenURI;
        emit requestedCollectible(requestId);
    }
    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomNumber) internal override{
        address dogOwner = requestIdToSender[requestId];
        string memory tokenURI = requestIdToTokenURI[requestId];
        uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;
        _safeMint(dogOwner, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        Breed dogBreed = Breed(randomNumber % 3); 
        tokenIdToBreed[newItemId] = dogBreed;
        requestIdToTokenId[requestId] = newItemId;
        tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
    }
    function setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) public {
        require(
            _isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId),
            "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved"
        );
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, _tokenURI);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste your code and not pictures? Images aren't discoverable by search engines very well

Comment: @patrickcollins just updated it - good idea, I'll keep that in mind for my future posts as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `brownie.config.yaml`, you are importing `OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0`, but in your .sol you are importing `@oppenzeppelin/contracts/etc...`. You should import the dependency as it says in your config. `import "OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol`

Answer (score 1):

The OP issue is clear and the reason he can't use `@openzeppelin` import is the incorrect name of `brownie.config.yaml` file.

Edit: As per the documentation: The configuration file must be saved as `brownie-config.yaml`
https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this **without** changing the code/import in the smart contract. (As changing that will fix Brownie, but will in turn wreck Truffle.)

Better to do remapping in brownie-config.yaml (And as stated in one of the answers, you had actually done this, but you named the brownie(-)config.ymal --> brownie(.)config.yaml

What was likely causing you error.

Example:

```
   compiler:
      solc:
        remappings:
          - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.2"
```

Note: the Openzeppelin version may vary.