# Brownie: CompilerError: File outside of allowed directories

Tags: brownie

I'm trying to import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" to my contract but i encountered this error.
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

contracts/FundMe.sol:5:1: ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

[image]

This is my brownie_config.yaml

[image]

Comment: Does this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98289/issue-with-importing-chainlink-openzeppelin answer your question?

Comment: Yes i checked it too, but of no use. This damn error stuck me for 4 days. I don't know how to get out it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in the brownie-config.yaml file, i used underscore (which is wrong) instead of a dash.
correct form: brownie-config.yaml